# connect to neo4j in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, neo4j

### hi im can't connect  neo4j(4.1.1) in asp.net core

err=> 405 method not found

---

var neo4jClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/neo4j/tx"), "neo4j", "@$");
services.AddSingleton(neo4jClient);
neo4jClient.Connect();